# problem in use mongodb at real host in evennode.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i just uploaded my first project to a free node.js host in evennode but it does not work . i changed all my connecting code to the codes that evennode recommend but i can't use express which basically all my codes are with it . does any body know how should i config my connection ? sorry my english isn't very well.and this is my first Q in stackoverwflow :) .

this are my app.js codes

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var khatm = require('./khatm');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/khatm";


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

mongoose.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true}, 
function (e) {
    if (!e) {
    console.log("connect");
} else {
    console.log("not connected")
}
});
  app.use('/khatm', khatm);
  app.listen(3000);
```

and log says :

```
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50 MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/data/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:828:32)
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     at Mongoose.connect (/data/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     at Object.<anonymous> (/data/app/app.js:12:10)
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50   reason: TopologyDescription {
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     type: 'Single',
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     setName: null,
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     maxSetVersion: null,
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     maxElectionId: null,
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     servers: Map { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     stale: false,
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     compatible: true,
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     compatibilityError: null,
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     localThresholdMS: 15,
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50     commonWireVersion: null
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50   }
2020-07-28 13:10:15 fbe827e2fb50 }
```

i also tried this :

Evennode.com :"EvenNode provides environment variable called APP_CONFIG which holds all information necessary to connect to your MongoDB instance from your Node.js application."

i do not have APP_CONFIG and when i write mongodb database information (that is in my admin page) directly instead of using config.mongo.user i can't connect.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var khatm = require('./khatm');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoPassword = 'alireza';
var config = JSON.parse(process.env.APP_CONFIG);
var url = "mongodb://" + config.mongo.user + ":" + encodeURIComponent(mongoPassword) + "@" + config.mongo.hostString;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

mongoose.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true}, function (e) {
    if (!e) {
        console.log("connect");
        console.log(e);
    } else {
        console.log("not connected")
    }
});

app.use('/khatm', khatm);
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

and log says:

```
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632 MongooseServerSelectionError: Authentication failed.
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/data/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:828:32)
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     at Mongoose.connect (/data/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     at Object.<anonymous> (/data/app/app.js:13:10)
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632   reason: TopologyDescription {
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     setName: null,
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     maxSetVersion: null,
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     maxElectionId: null,
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     servers: Map {
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632       '9a.mongo.evennode.com:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632       '9b.mongo.evennode.com:27017' => [ServerDescription]
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     },
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     stale: false,
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     compatible: true,
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     compatibilityError: null,
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     localThresholdMS: 15,
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632     commonWireVersion: null
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632   }
2020-07-28 12:49:26 35e6f679b632 }
```

All tips will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Hi! Are there any specific error logs from evennode?

Comment: @tunmee Hi.errors are different . when i use their code it runs but i do not have access to express and app.khatm for example .as you can see some codes are in other file named khatm and when i use my code, log says not connected, i will add the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit old, answering it here in case it helps anyone else: I had repeated step for step what person asking question had (which is also what https://www.evennode.com/docs/mongodb#connect has) and my app run and connected successfully.

Are you sure you set up your password for Mongodb at "Information" page at admin.evennode.com for your app?

There is a link to 'Change password' at the bottom of the page, MongoDB section.